# NotifySourceUpdated & Binding.SourceUpdated not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My event below (`OnSourceUpdated`) is not getting handled.

**XAML:**

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Side, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 Width="100"/>
        <TextBlock Background="Yellow" 
                   Text="{Binding Side, Mode=OneWay, 
                                  NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                   Width="100" 
                   SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated"
                   Binding.SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

**C#:**

```
....
MyStackPanel.DataContext = new MyItemClass() { Side = "Test" };
....

private void OnSourceUpdated(Object sender, DataTransferEventArgs args)
{
    var i = args.Property;
}

public class MyItemClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _side;
    public string Side
    {
        get { return _side; }

        set 
        {
            _side = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Side");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have all the relevant settings done like `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` & `SourceUpdated` & `Binding.SourceUpdated` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated.aspx): **Binding.SourceUpdated** attached event occurs when a value is transferred from the binding target to the binding source, but only for bindings with the NotifyOnSourceUpdated value set to true

In the Binding of TextBlock, there is no value transfer from the binding target (`TextBlock.Text`) to the binding source (`Side`). Thus SourceUpdated cannot be fired.

Instead SourceUpdated can be fired on the first binding. Indeed here the target binding `TextBox.Text` can change the binding source (`Side`).

Comment: Yes. Got it. So I added `NotifyTargetUpdated` in `TextBox` & handled `Binding.SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated"` on the `StackPanel` level. So then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm thinking your approach to updating is a bit strange. Is there a reason you're not just going with

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding foo, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

If you're just interested in updates coming from source, that's normally the way of doing it. Calling

```
OnPropertyChanged( "PropertyName" )
```

covers the rest.